# Phsysical Home Button onStop in Android

Tags: android

Does the Home Button calls `onStop()` method in Android or only `onPause()`? Can some one explain whole Physical Buttons events?

Comment: [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-intercepting-physical-key-events/) might be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can override all physical button events except home. Home will cause all your applications to go to background so this process will cause onPause() followed by onStop() for your application.

You can override any other physical keys with onKeyUp.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please extend your answer with answering all of the asked above? What about the other buttons like Back? What methods are they calling?

Comment: As I have said. It can be overrided. You back button can be fireing off your broswer to rate your app(although not recommended). Backbutton can vary even by default. ex close popup. close slidingmenu. close fragment. pop activity from stack. It varies.